# API to Get Password policies in Google Admin SDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to get password policies using Google Admin SDK, but unfortunately cannot find an endpoint for it.

Pls help.

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue, I currently did not find any way to retrieve that one :/

Comment: @Vasek-TomC. Have you found a way to fetch password policies from the Google API?

Comment: Unfortunately no, may Google update their APIs and make that possible one day